# How to calculate sum of instances' values for each index in a list using just Numpy and/or Pandas without writing loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes:

**df_tx** is a dataframe of address-to-address transactions

```
from_address,to_address,value
0,334,31337
1,335,19900000000000000000
2,336,599989500000000000000
3,337,100000000000000000000
4,338,10000000000000000
5,6,50000000000000000
6,5,5000000000000000
7,62,20000000000000000000
8,23,803989500000000000000
0,339,0
9,39,100000000000000000000
```

**df_id** is a dataframe of the list of addresses and corresponding balances

```
id,balance
0,0
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,0
5,0
6,0
7,0
8,0
9,0
10,0
```

Every balance for all ids start at 0. If the final balances have negative values, that is okay in this case.

An address being in the **'from_address'** column represents that the transaction's **'value'** gets taken away from that address's balance.

An address being in the **'to_address'** column represents that the transaction's **'value'** gets added to that address's balance.

My goal is to use these rules to calculate the balance for all addresses.

Below is my code to calculate this:

```
for i in range(df_id['id'].iloc[0], df_id['id'].iloc[-1]):

    out_vals = np.select(df_tx['from_address'] == i, df_tx['value'])
    in_vals = np.select(df_tx['to_address'] == i, df_tx['value'])

    out_total = np.sum(out_vals)
    in_total = np.sum(in_vals)
    net_total = out_total - in_total

    df_id.loc[i, 'balance'] = df_id.loc[i, 'balance'] + net_total
```

This code works, but my problem is that the for loop slows it down.

**Q: How do I write this using only Numpy and Pandas without the for loop?**

This code needs to be as fast as possible since the full dataset on which this will run will have over **1 Billion** rows in each input dataframe.

Memory usage is not an issue at the moment, even for loading a dataset of this size.

**All criticism and suggestions of my code and general approach are welcome and appreciated. Thank you in advance.**

Comment: The entries in the `value` column of `df_tx` are extremely large, e.g. in the range of `1e20`. So much so, that it becomes non-trivial for the datatypes `np.int64` and `np.float64`. Is this desired?

Comment: @7shoe Thank you for the comment. I forgot to mention that upon reading in the dataset, I cast the 'value' column string values into np.longdouble and then multiply them by 1e-18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need any intermediate balances, you're probably best off using `pandas` functions on entire columns:

```
withdrawals = df_tx.groupby('from_address')['value'].sum()
deposits = df_tx.groupby('to_address')['value'].sum()
final_balance = df_id + deposits - withdrawals
```

Comment: Seems to work properly. How do I confirm that this does not get rid of duplicate values before the sum aggregate function is called?